# windows cmd function equivalent

Tags: windows, shell, console, cmd

Is it possible to translate this to windows console commands?

`for f in *.flac; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec alac "${f%.flac}.m4a"; done`

Comment: What language is this in now. The answer is going to be `for /f %f in (*.flac) do ....` but I can't make out how the arguments to ffmpeg depend on `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
for %f in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -acodec alac "%~nf.m4a"
```

Comment: Yep that nearly did the trick, I also needed quotes around the %f and the %~nf.m4a so that it worked for file names with spaces. Could you edit your answer with this, `for %f in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -acodec alac "%~nf.m4a"` Btw this converts flac files to apple lossless files so that you can play them on itunes.